How to embed single quotes, inside single quotes, inside for loop
Here's what I'm trying to accomplish...
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('PsExec -AcceptEula -NoBanner \\HOSTNAME -H -N 8 -S WMIC Product Where "Name like '%%adobe%%'" Get Description,IdentifyingNumber,Version /Value^|Find "^="') Do @Echo %%A

However, it fails because the first internal single quote appears to act like the second external single quote within the parens, then the rest of the code just bombs with the "Invalid Get Expression" error coming from the WMIC error handling.
Is there a way to embed those internal single quotes inside the external single quotes? If not, I can't see a way to use "like '%%something%%'" with the WMIC command.
